# EFS taking longer time to respond requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, solr, amazon-efs

**Description:**

I have a project running on an AWS server which is taking too long to complete.

The project consists of dynamic form fields which are saved with Solr search Indexer. My simple Solr Queries are taking 2 minutes of time to successfully execute the query. I have kept Solr in a EFS mapped folder on AWS instance.

I don't want to move Solr on EBS.

**Solutions I have tried:**

- EFS Performance Mode : Both General purpose and Max I/O still taking around 2 Minutes.
- EFS Throughput Mode : Tried Burst mode taking roughly around same time.

Comment: what is your goal?  Do you want it to run faster?

Comment: yes i want the response to be faster.

Comment: So what is the Solr query that is taking such as long time? How many rows? How many documents in your store? Are there any independent sets of documents that can be spread across multiple, distinct servers instead, or do all documents have to be considered for each query?

Comment: For Curl replace query its taking 2 minutes 40 seconds. 
There are 122000 documents and all the documents are to be considered for query.